# How to lock multiple table rows in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, locking

I have two tables, i will leave the **create table** statements for both of them below.

I would like to know if it is possible to lock the corresponding rows in **currency_details**  when someone is modifying a row on **currency** and vice versa.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currency (
                id VARCHAR(8),
                name VARCHAR(20),
                PRIMARY KEY (id)
                );
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currency_details (
                id VARCHAR(8) REFERENCES currency ON DELETE CASCADE,
                info VARCHAR(80),
                PRIMARY KEY (id)
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only locks that are taken automatically is a `FOR KEY SHARE` row lock on `currency` if you insert rows into `currency_details`.

Other than that, you could write a trigger that performs an appropriate `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the other table.

But that is an unusual requirement; perhaps it is not really necessary to lock those rows.